# Flush files at unexpected end of fortran program

Tags: linux, fortran, buffer

I wonder if there is some trick to flush (dump the buffer) all the output files when a runing fortran program end in a unexpected way (an external stop for example). It would be great if there is a way to set this in the language, however if there is an external way (linux) could be also usefull. I think that may be there is a way to write the buffer in this situations... may be capturing a signal? I don't know.

Thanks in advance.

MOTIVATION: When there is some unexpected end in the program, dump the buffer could be very usefull to debug, but if this dump is only in this case, it is posible to avoid the unnecessary "flush" sintax that consume the resources.

Comment: Read your compiler docs if you want to try signal handling -- I suspect the signals you can catch/handle are already handled by nicely closing files though. (No way you will handle a kill signal for example)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
open(unit = 10, file = "toto")
....
call flush(10)
```

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/FLUSH.html

According to vladimir F comments if your compiler suport fortran 2003 standard you can use `flush` as a statement.

```
open(unit = 10, file = "toto")
...
flush(10)
```

Comment: This is non-standard. In Fortran 2003 `flush` is a statement, so used without `call`.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question - flush-ing after every write is exactly what he wants to avoid if I understand correctly . -- The correct answer is simply "no" though, at least not via fortran language.

Comment: Thanks george. I suspected that